# Http,Get with a string parameter returns http 404

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to do a http.Get request by passing a single string as parameter.

The angular code I have tried so far are,

1)

```
 var abseURL = 'http://localhost:17493/api/UsersApi/GetUsersByEmail/';
 var email ='testemail@domain.com';
 $http.get(abseURL + email).then(OnComplete, OnError);
```

- returns a http 404 error

2)

```
$http({
        url: abseURL,
        method: "GET",
        params: { email: 'testemail@domain.com'}
    }).then(OnComplete,OnError);
```

- The above http.get request returns a Http 500 error

My webApi controller method is defined as,

```
        [ActionName("GetUsersByEmail")]
        [CamelCasedApiControllerAttribute]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsersByEmail(string email)
        {
            Users users = await db.Users.FindAsync(email);
            if (users == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(users);
        }
```

Also in my Global.asax.cs file I have mapped the routes as follows

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {              
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "ActionApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
             );

            });

        }
```

> If I pass an Int paramter it find the correct action in my WebApiController
>   But when I change the call with a string parameter, it it unable to find the correct action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rename email parameter to id:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUsersByEmail(string id)
{
    Users users = await db.Users.FindAsync(id);
    if (users == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(users);
}
```

Comment: Yes this did work provided I made the Get call as `$http.get(abseURL + id).then(OnComplete, OnError);` * id being a string. If I wrapped the parameter and made the Get request as  below it would return a Http 500 error.                       `$http({
        url: abseURL,
        method: "GET",
        params: { email: 'testemail@domain.com'}
    }).then(OnComplete,OnError);`

Comment: @AJ17 - I know this is old, but maybe it will help others. The reason why using `params` failed for you is you did not rename the param - you still used `email`. If you renamed the param to `id` it would have worked: `$http({ url: abseURL, method: "GET", params: { id: 'testemail@domain.com'} }).then(OnComplete,OnError);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the routing is not setup to handle this. You could try using the following instead:

```
var abseURL = 'http://localhost:17493/api/UsersApi/GetUsersByEmail/?email=';
var email ='testemail@domain.com';
$http.get(abseURL + email).then(OnComplete, OnError);
```